# Notice: Undefined variable: router_address in C:\wamp\www\public\index.php on line 38

Tags: php, mysql

i get this kinda error: 
Notice: Undefined variable: router_address in C:\wamp\www\public\index.php on line 38
and i don't understand why even though everything seems right
please help

```
require_once'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{ 
$routername = trim($_POST['routername']);
$router_brand = trim($_POST['router_brand']);
$router_type = trim($_POST['router_type']);
if (isset($_POST['router_address'])) {$router_address = 
$_POST['router_address']; }
if($routername=="") { 
$error[] = "provide router name !"; 
}
elseif($router_brand=="") {
$error[] = "provide  router brand !"; 
}
elseif( $router_type=="") {
$error[] = "provide router type !";
}
elseif($router_address=="") {
$error[] = "provide router address  !";
}else
{
if($router->register($routername,$router_brand,$router_type,$router_address)) 
{
 $router->redirect('index.php?joined');
  }
}
}
```

Comment: router_address is not defined. define it. isset($_POST['router_address'] if this fails you get the undefined error.

Comment: i did try it but then i get an error in elseif($router_address=="") and in the register function what should i do?

Comment: $router_address = '' add this before isset($_POST['router_address']). if isset fails then empty address is inserted to db this will result in sql error if column is not null.